# cuda setting cudaError

Tags: debugging, cuda

How to oneself set cudaError variable in a cuda kernel (e.g. for conditions which are not fatal but logically wrong).

My cuda kernel is unexpectedly spitting nan values and I am debugging this.

Answer (score 2):

The runtime API error reporting mechanism can't be used for user device code to report errors.

If you want your device code to return an abnormal status indicator, the easiest way to do it would be to declared a static global memory flag variable and have any thread which encounters an error write to that flag. If you want to thread to abort the kernel, you can do something like this:

```
__device__ int errorflag;

__global__ void kernel()
{
    // Processing code here

    if (errorcondition) {
        errorflag=errorcode;
        __threadfence();
        asm("trap;");
    }
}
```

This is lead to an abnormal termination error signalled from the runtime, with your error condition saved in `errorflag`. You can read back from `errorflag` using `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` in host code to check the result. A pointer to zero-copy memory could also potentially be used if you prefer, in which case you would need to use a `__threadfence_system()` call instead to ensure the write was flushed to the host before the trap was executed.

Comment: How would one catch and clear that trap?After triggering that trap, my application seems unable to recover.  cudaGetLastError() returns '4' the first time and '0' the second (indicating cleared status), but down stream I'm still getting either a runtime unspecified launch errors (err=4) or a driver launch failed error (err=700).

Comment: How would one catch and clear that trap?  After triggering that trap, my application seems unable to recover.  cudaGetLastError() returns '4' the first time and '0' the second (indicating cleared status), but down stream I'm still getting either a runtime unspecified launch errors (err=4) or a driver launch failed error (err=700).